# NHibernate filter weird SQL translation

Tags: nhibernate

I'm trying to use NHibernate filters but I'm obtaining a really weird SQL translation
In the mapping file I have this fragment:

```
<filter name="onlyMProv" 
  condition="Abbreviation in (SELECT AllowedAbbreviation from dbo.AllowedDistricts)" />
```

in the code then I wrote

```
session.EnableFilter("onlyMProv");
var districts = session.CreateQuery("from District");
```

but nHibernate translate this into

```
select [fields...] 
from dbo.Districts district0_ where district0_.Abbreviation in 
    (SELECT district0_.AllowedAbbreviation from dbo.AllowedDistricts)
```

Which returns, a "Column name AllowedAbbreviation is not valid".

As you can see it put the alias district0_ in the subquery... 
Any idea ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all columns without prefix are treated as columns of the owning entity. simple solution:

```
condition="Abbreviation in (SELECT ad.AllowedAbbreviation from dbo.AllowedDistricts ad)"
```

Comment: Hi firo and thank you for your assistance, actually your suggestion work perfectly for the illustrated case, however now I have the same problem If I use a subquery on a table-function call, i.e.     condition="Abbreviation IN (SELECT ad.AllowedAbbreviation FROM dbo.MyFunc(1) ad)" will be translated in     [...] where district0_.Abbreviation IN (SELECT ad.AllowedAbbreviation FROM dbo.MyFunc(1) district0_.ad) [...] resulting in sqlserver screaming that it doesn't know "ad". Any other precious suggestion ?

Comment: hmm maybe `(dbo.MyFunc(1)) ad` or `(dbo.MyFunc(1) ad)`